# How to get the size of a struct member without instantiating the struct without using macros?

Tags: c++, templates

I don't have a C++ environment available to me right now, and a co-worker wants some advice on how to replace the following macro with a template function,

```
#define member_sizeof(T,F) sizeof(((T *)0)->F)
```

I got this so far;

```
struct X { int x; double z; }; 
template<class T> inline T member_size(); 
int main() 
{    
    std::cout << sizeof(member_size<X>().x) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << sizeof(member_size<X>().z) << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

But the goal is to get the `sizeof()` a member without having to instantiate the `struct`.

And it has to work with *International Standard for C++, ISO IS 14882:2003*, no C++11 unfortunately.

#### If there is one, what would be the equivalent template solution?

Comment: You need a macro, because the name of a member isn't meaningful when it's not attached to the name of its class or an object of that class.

Comment: What is the problem with calling `sizeof(type::member)`?

Comment: agreed. Macro is longer than direct invocation...

Comment: @juanchopanza Does that work? Does it perhaps give the `sizeof` a pointer-to-member? Note that `member` is presumably not static, since it's accessed through a faux instance pointer `(T*)0` here. Edit: I'll be damned, [it appears to work](http://ideone.com/HFWCfO).

Comment: I believe `sizeof(type::member)` was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @delnan Yes, it does, But not in C++03. See here http://ideone.com/2b9i8z.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, it is possible to write `sizeof(T::F)` directly, where `T` is the type and `F` is the name of the member. So no need for a macro.

In C++03 this is not allowed (§5.1/10). As far as I know, the macro is the best way to do this. The name of a member is meaningless on its own; you need the class it belongs to, or an object of that class, and all constructions are awkward so it is best to just define a macro like the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

From someone accidentally banned:

> No, template cannot simply accept member name. There are evil workaround with preprocessor metaprogramming and TMP using SFINAE [here](https://github.com/jerrycheng567/reflection), but it's just plainly evil and unreadable, and IMHO, simple macro seems to be a good choice.